# A limit that does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits

Let  $$A_{n}=\{0,1/n,2/n,...\}$$

Let $C_{n}=|S{\cap}A_{n}|$ for a set $S$. Find a set $S$ for which the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{C_{n}}{n}$$ does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is $C_n$ the *cardinality* of $S{\cap}A_{n}$? If so, we could find many sets, such as $S=\mathbb R$, for which  $S{\cap}A_{n}$ is infinitely large, making both $C_n$ and the limit not exist.

Comment: @Daulton Why did you delete your post. I don't really understand the set your proposed. E.G. for n=2; 0 and 1/2 are in the intersection so cardinality isn't 1

Comment: @user108605: I realized that I was mistaken. You pointed out an error, and I saw another one. I was in a hurry to help my mother-in-law with a problem and I did not have time to correct my mistake, so I just deleted what was not clearly true. Do you want more thoughts on your the modification to your question, where $S \cap A_n$ is finite?

Comment: @Daulton yes please.

Comment: @daulton. Obviously we are looking for some set that will make the cardinality osscilate but it seems almost impossible

Comment: @Daulton I've thought of very simple one: S={0.5}

Comment: @daulton no doesn't work